# 301 Redirect site in Drupal 6

Tags: redirection

I have a site in Drupal 6 which needs to be 301 redirected to external site. I can see .htaccess file in Drupal which has the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/example/php.ini
    <Files php.ini>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

But while following this document in Drupal for 301 redirection: https://www.drupal.org/node/38960, it says we need to find "IfModule mod_rewrite.c" to write rewrite rule. In my .htaccess file I don't have "IfModule mod_rewrite.c". What should I do to add the rewrite rule in this case?
Should I need to enable any module to achieve this goal.
Any suggestion?